# Formatting js-joda Duration instance

Tags: js-joda

I'd like to display a chrono of elapsed time since the beginning of an operation to a user. I create a Duration instance from a number of seconds, but then, I can't find a way to properly format it like `00:00:23`. Do I have to manually get each time component (hours, minutes, seconds) and assemble them?

The [Formatting](https://js-joda.github.io/js-joda/manual/formatting.html) section of the docs specifies that a `DateTimeFormatter` can only be passed to the `format` method of `LocalDate`, `LocalTime`, `LocalDateTime`, or `ZonedDateTime` instance, and `Duration` does not have such method.

Comment: Have you been able to find a way to format js-joda durations? I'm struggling with the same thing currently.

Comment: If I remember well, I had created my own function to format a duration. However, I haven't used `js-joda` since then.

Comment: What stack are you using?
In my case, I was using spring on the backend and eventually found a way to allow the backend to take over the formatting part instead of jQuery. However, I'm still interested in seeing other solutions to this issue.

Comment: Initially, I was using MomentJS, but for my last big project, I decided to go with DayJS, a drop-in replacement with immutability and modularity. It suits my needs pretty well!